# ROS node consuming 100 % of CPU load . How?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS - Kinetic , and Ubuntu 16.04 OS .
ROS - node uses a synchronizer for Three messages , to be subscribed from Three other ROS nodes .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269404/ros-node-consuming-100-%-of-cpu-load-.-how-?/) by [Prithvi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/31673/prithvi-raj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please provide us with more information - in this case: a snippet that shows how you run your main loop.

Are you running your own `while { ..; ros::spinOnce(); ..; }` or are you using `ros::spin()`? If the former: be sure to add a `ros::Rate::sleep()` in there, or you basically have a busy-wait.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prithvi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/31673/prithvi-raj/) on 2017-08-23**:
Thank You . It is resolved .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-23**:
Can you tell us what the cause was? Did you have a busy-while-loop without a sleep?

**Comment by [Prithvi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/31673/prithvi-raj/) on 2017-08-23**:
Yes . I was using ros::spinOnce inside a while loop  , without rate.sleep() .